# Proving a property of rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let be $m,b\in\Bbb{N}$ and $A=(a_{ij})\in\Bbb{R}^{m \times n} $ It applies that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}= 0, \forall i\in \{ 1,\cdots,m\}$ Show that $Rank(A) < n$.

\

I guess it's a crucial point that the $rank(A) < n$ and it's not $rank(A) = n$

Actually I have difficulties to understand this part $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}= 0, \forall\in \{ 1,\cdots,m\}$.

Do we accumulate the elements $ a_{i1}+ \cdots a_{in}$? So is it the sum of every elements in the matrix? But it makes no sense to me. Thank you for your helps in advance.

Comment: Do you mean for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots m\} $?

Comment: yes, I have edited the question, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each and every column of the matrix sums to $0$. Hence, the $n$-dimensional vector of all $1$'s is mapped to the null vector. This gives a non-trivial nullspace, hence rank is $<n$.